# Min-width at body causes scrollbar issues

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a responsive Tagcloud. 
But somehow I have problems in the max-width 400px part. 
 Although Im already using width: auto and box sizing border-box, it generates a horizontal scrollbar at 326px in Chrome as u can see in the Picture below.

[image]

Anybody got a Solution for this?

```css
body{
 color:#122e45;
 font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
 line-height:16px;
 background-color:#fafafa;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 min-width:320px;
}

/* Helpers */
.before:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.after:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

#tagCloud {
 max-width:960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#tagCloud .quarter {
 width:25%;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 max-width:240px;
 float:left;
}


#tagCloud ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 font-size:14px;
 padding:0;
}

#tagCloud ul li {
 height:26px;
}

#tagCloud ul li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#122e45;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
 #tagCloud .quarter {
  min-width:33.3333%;
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last {
  clear:left;
  min-width:100%;
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last:before {
     display: table;
     content: " ";
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last:after {
     content: " ";
     display: table;
     clear: both;
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last li {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 20px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
 #tagCloud .quarter {
  min-width:50%;
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last li {
  display:list-item;
  float:none;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width:100%;
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last {
  clear:none;
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last:before {
     content: "";
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last:after {
     content: "";
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 #tagCloud .quarter {
  width: auto;
     float: none;
     max-width: initial;
     min-width: initial;
     box-sizing:border-box;
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last:before {
     content: "";
 }
 
 #tagCloud .last:after {
     content: "";
 }
}
```

```html
 <div id="cmsContainer">
  <div id="tagCloud" class="cmsElement before after">
     <div class="quarter">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">IT Jobs</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Jobs für Ingenieure</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Fahrzeugbau & Zulieferer</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Vertrieb</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Maschinenbau</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Beratung, Consulting</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rechnungswesen</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Immobilien und Bau</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="quarter">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Jobs im Marketing</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Pharma, Chemie</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">80.000 EUR Plus</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sachbearbeitung</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Controlling</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Ärzte und Mediziner</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Pflege</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Jobs für SAP-Spezialisten</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="quarter">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Sekretariat</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Recht und Steuern</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Banken, Finanzen</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Versicherung</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Energie</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Jugend- & Sozialarbeit</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Behörden, Kommunen</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Verbände, Vereine</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Schule und Bildung</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="quarter last">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Auslandsjobs</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Direkteinstieg</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Trainee</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Ausbildung</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Praktikum</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Angebote der Woche</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Jobs nach Einsatzort</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Jobs nach Thema</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Jobs nach Unternehmen</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I would say its because your vertical scroll bar takes up some of the horizontal width, hence the bar appearing. Try reducing the max-width value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update css for body as  -

```css
body {
    color: #122e45;
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Remove min-width CSS property applied to it, then scrollbar will not visible in low resolution. However if you want to keep min-width property then decrease the value for same.

Comment: By removing the min width attribute the scrollbar disapears. however, i want to keep it since the body itself cant be smaller than 320px on any other device than desktops. the weird thing is, that the scrollbar appears at 327 as shown in the picture above. but the body is at min- width 320px so how does he appear?

Comment: For more understanding on this I would suggest you to go through the window height and width properties. As the page has vertical scrollbar, the width of vertical scrollbar also comes in to the picture, due to which horizontal scrollbar is coming. I hope its explanatory to you.

Comment: ok so because the content itself doesnt fit in the height, the right scrollbar pushes the window smaller, so the scrollbar in the bottom appears aswell?

Comment: yes..you can verify with and without vertical scrollbar, then you will get more understanding.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the min width attribute as stated by u guys. But I also found another way that lets me allow to keep it. by removing the before and after pseudo elements and than keep the float left. but that doesnt make sense at all since 100% width elements dont need to be floated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `min-width` attribute to your body which gets inherited to other elements of your html - such as your cmsContainer. [**Pic**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks8Kd.png)

So you can either remove that property from your body:

**CSS**

```
body {
  color:#122e45;
  font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
  line-height:16px;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Or, you can override it for the elements that inherit it. For example:

**CSS**

```
body {
  color:#122e45;
  font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
  line-height:16px;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  max-width: 320px;
}

#cmsContainer {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also simply just reduce the `max-width` value.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `min-width:320px;` from the body class, it'll work.

Its working fine for me, hope this will resolve your issue.

Or if body width is important to keep, then add one more class:

```
body body{min-width:auto!important;}
```